# Convert Facebook created_time to Ago Format

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have trying to create a function `timeAgo(time)` that take a
Facebook created_time (2016-01-15T20:31:30+0000) and convert it to ago time.

**Ex:** just now, 2 minutes, hours, days, ...

```
function timeAgo(time){
var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
  diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
  day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
  return;

return day_diff == 0 && (
      diff < 60 && "just now" ||
      diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
      diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
      diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
      diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
  day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
  day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
  day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
}
```

---

Call it

`timeAgo(data[i].created_time);`

---

It works on all the browsers except Firefox.

---

**Chrome**

[image]

---

**Firefox**

It kept showing as undefined.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to check the regular expression, and also use fire bug. Undefined is returned in the first condition.

Comment: I tested that if you remove the replace calls on your date string before creation of date it works fine. So just use `var date = new Date((time || ""))` . Is there a reason you are replacing '-' with '/' and removing 'T Z' from the string?

Comment: Your suggestion, works !